# Cases bug in overleaf beamer?

Tags: beamer, amsmath, cases

I read there was a cases bug in overleaf in beamer.. I am not sure if this is true. But my code will not work now, but if I remove the following code it does work.

I am using the amsmath package I have no idea why this does not work, it works in

```
      \begin{equation}
       \frac{1}{\phi(q)}\sum_{\chi\, \mod q} \overline{\chi(a)}\chi(n) = 
\begin{cases}
     &1 \quad \text{if} \quad n \equiv a \
     \mod q\\
     &0     \quad \quad \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}       
   \end{equation}
  \end{block}
```

Comment: As always please post a full minimal example that others can test. Not these out of context sniplets.

Comment: Plus you're using cases wrong why are you starting those lines with &?

Comment: Please wrap this snippet in a compilable example beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.  That will allow potential helpers to copy-and-paste the example for experimentation, rather than having to invent the context themselves.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote,

> I read there was a cases bug in overleaf in beamer. I am not sure if this is true.

Not being prone to putting much stock in conspiracy theories, I strongly doubt this claim. Do you have a reference?

Anyway, there is no need to go bug-hunting, as a quick inspection of your code produces an easily verifiable alternative diagnosis of the situation: You're not using the `cases` syntax correctly. Instead of

```
\begin{cases}
   &1 \quad \text{if} \quad n \equiv a \ \mod q\\
   &0 \quad \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
```

you should be writing

```
\begin{cases}
   1 & \text{if $n \equiv a \mod q$}\\
   0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
```

---

Making this code snippet into a standalone compilable example, I get

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\smashoperator' macro
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\phi(q)} \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{\chi\bmod q}}
\overline{\chi(a)}\,\chi(n) = 
\begin{cases}
   1 & \text{if $n \equiv a \mod q$}\\
   0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```